# Чтение строки из файла

Tags: while, java, файлы

К примеру, имеется текстовый файл с содержимым:

```
строка1  
строка2  
строка3  
строка4  
строка5
```

Читается файл ридером в цикле.

Вопрос: как в цикле, получив строку "строка1", сразу за один раз захватить еще строку "строка2"?

В `String` подходящих методов не нашел.

Comment: А почему бы не сохранить "строка1" в переменной, и обратиться к ней на следующей итерации цикла?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня в первой строке число, которое нужно использовать во второй строке, в методе substring (0, полученное число);  
всё вроде бы просто, но каждая строка в цикле читается отдельно, не получается реализовать.

Comment: @Sergey_21: Ну, а что мешает сохранить это число в переменную?

Comment: Текста много, строка с числом и строка для обрезки могут быть где угодно. Строка для обрезки находится прямо под строкой с числом, не могу узнать, когда именно применять это самое число.  
Попробуйте обрезать http://pastebin.com/EENs5krJ   
Только выполнять это нужно в цикле while.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Работает.

Comment: @VladD,
А почему не BufferedReader.ready?

Comment: @smackmychi: Я не знаток Java, нашёл первый попавшийся пример в интернете, который читал строки в цикле, и адаптировал под задачу. Если вы знаете, как написать идиоматично, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так: http://ideone.com/PkIKMO

```
Integer trimSize = null;

while (in.ready()) {
    String currentLine = in.readLine();
    if (trimSize != null)
        currentLine = currentLine.substring(0, trimSize);
    if (currentLine.startsWith("size:"))
        trimSize = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.substring(5));
    else
        trimSize = null;
}
```

Comment: @VladD
Если пользоваться BufferedReader, то можно использовать метод ready() для проверки наличия данных.

    while(reader.ready()){
        //...do smthng
    }

Comment: @smackmychi: А как тогда получить текущую строку? Откуда взять значение `currentLine`?

Comment: @VladD
.s

    read()
    //Reads a single character.

    int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
    //Reads characters into a portion of an array.

    String readLine()
    //Reads a line of text.

Дело ведь не в том, что вы что-то сделали неверно, просто мне показалось удобнее и лаконичнее использовать готовый метод.

Comment: @smackmychi: Ага, понял, спасибо. Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо! я решил вопрос первым предложенным способом.
Может кому и будет когда-нибудь полезно - http://pastebin.com/FVA1tKUm

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder вам в помощь или

```
String str = "";
while(reader.ready){
   str += reader.readline();
}
```

Comment: Вопрос решен!